# Add and append an inner div to a div and attach a function to it

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have several divs in my container div. In each div i want to add and append another div dynamically then attach a function to it. For this case i want to change the background color of the parent div(the div to which the inner div is attached to).
This is the code i have so far

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

 .mydiv{
 Position: relative;
 Width: 600px;
 Height: 200px;
 Border: 2px solid red;
 }

 .decorate{
 Position: absolute;
 Top: 5px;
 Left:  400px;
 Width: 100px;
 Height: 40px;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id ='container'>
<div class ='mydiv' id='div1'> 
</div>
<div class ='mydiv' id='div2'> 
</div>
<div class ='mydiv' id='div3'> 
</div>
<div class ='mydiv' id='div4'> 
</div>
</div>

<script type ='text/JavaScript'>
document.ready(function(){

//create buttons/divs
$('.mydiv').append $('<div 
id ='+ $(this).attr(id) + ' class 
="decorate" + '>Decorate</div>');

// attach function
 $('.decorate').click(function (){
    $(parent).css ('background':'blue');
 });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are many basic syntax errors.

Comment: Shouldn't `+ ' class ="decorate" + '>Decorate</div>');` be `+ ' class ="decorate">Decorate</div>');`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As was suggested, there are some basic syntax errors that need to be addressed, such as your `document.ready()` should start with `$` or `jQuery` like so: `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` or `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".mydiv").each(function(i, el) {
    var newDiv = $("<div>", {
      class: "decorate",
      id: $(el).attr("id") + "-" + (i + 1)
    });
    newDiv.click(function(event) {
      $(el).toggleClass("selected");
    });
    newDiv.appendTo(el);
  });
});
```

```css
.mydiv {
  Position: relative;
  Width: 600px;
  Height: 200px;
  Border: 2px solid red;
}

.mydiv.selected {
  background-color: blue;
}

.decorate {
  Position: absolute;
  Top: 5px;
  Left: 400px;
  Width: 100px;
  Height: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div class='mydiv' id='div1'>
  </div>
  <div class='mydiv' id='div2'>
  </div>
  <div class='mydiv' id='div3'>
  </div>
  <div class='mydiv' id='div4'>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see here that all the Syntax has been corrected. Additionally, using `.each()` we can iterate each DIV and append the item and bind the function.

Using `.toggleClass()` we can easily add/remove a class to show the item has been clicked.

When appending new HTML elements, if you are using an ID attribute, it must be unique. So when adding the ID to the new element, we must create a unique ID for it.

If you want to bind the event callback before the items are created, you can use `.on()`. Example:

```
$(".mydiv").on("click", ".decorations", function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");
});
```